# Como evitar emails duplicados no banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, cakephp

Estou criando um CMS simples em CakePHP, com o intuito de aprender a usar framework. Dentro do meu CMS, na parte de administração do site, tem uma aba que se chama *enviar emails* e nesta aba visualizamos todos os emails que foram cadastrados pelo administrador. No entanto na hora de cadastrar um  emails ele permite que cadastremos um mesmo email repetidas vezes. Como faço para eliminar esta falha?

Comment: Eu não conheço o Cake, mas a regra de validação deve ser como a maioria dos FW, procure pelo atributo `unique`, ou faça no controller uma verificação do email antes de cadastrar. Aqui encontrei algumas respostas que podem ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461267/cakephp-isunique-for-2-fields

Answer (score 2):

Basta você definir 2 regras no campo de email.

Dentro do seu model, que possui este campo, fica desta forma:

```
public $validate = array(
// Aqui vai o nome do campo
'email' => array(
    // O nome que você quiser dar na validação do campo
    'rule1Email' => array(
        // Tipo de regra
        // parãmetro true verifica se o host é válido
        'rule' => array('email', true),
        //Sua mensagem de erro para esta regra
        'message' => 'Insira um email válido',
        //Obriga a preencher
        'required' => true,
        //Se quer limitar a apenas alguma action
        'on' => 'create'
    ),
    //Outra regra para o mesmo campo.
    'rule2isUnique' => array(
        //Tipo de regra
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        //Sua mensagem de erro para esta regra
        'message' => 'Email já cadastrado'
        )
    )
);
```

Fonte e outras opções:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

basta você colocar o campo onde é registrado o email como UNIQUE, se um insert tentar inserir um valor igual ele não irá permitir.

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`aplicacao` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC);
```

caso um insert tente registrar um valor que já existe irá retornar erro como abaixo

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'teste@teste.com' for key 'email_UNIQUE'
```

assim você garante o banco, a aplicação já é outro assunto.